# Validating Dropdown Value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown as Select City I want to to the validation such a way that when user does not select any value from the drop down it must give message as "Please Select your City"

I have tried this way but of no use:

```
[Required]
public IEnumerable<LocationInformation> AllLocations 

@Html.ZurbLocationDropDownFor(model => model.AllLocations, Model.AllLocations, "twelve", "Select your city", Model.SelectedLocationId, addr)
```

Pls let me know!!!

Comment: Use requiredfieldvalidator

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the MVC. But using JQuery it can be done as follows:

Suppose `id` of your dropdown is `ddlCity`.

```
if($('ddlCity > [Selected]').length = 0)
    {
        alert("Please Select your City");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where `AllLocations` is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` this is what you need:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationsId, 
                      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllLocations, 
                      "Please select")
```